# How can I manually reuse KOMA variables?

Tags: koma-script, metadata

I am attaching/embedding an `invoice` environment to the end of a `scrlttr2` letter. I am improvising a header atop and outside the `invoice` environment with 3 `minipage` environments.

In the last of these, I want to restate my name and address. How do I reuse the `\setkomavar` `{fromname}`, `{fromaddress}`, etc., without having to define new commands?

Failing that, if new commands like `\myname`, `\myphone`, etc. are best way to do this, how do I make them inherit the `\setkomavar`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `\usekomavar{<var>}` as it is described in the manual I guess ;-)

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}

\usepackage[english]{babel}


\setkomavar{fromname}{John Doe}
\newcommand*{\myname}{\usekomavar{fromname}}

\begin{document}
\usekomavar{fromname} or \myname
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, I overlooked that in the manual, which I have indeed been poring over. :)

Comment: Your welcome. Btw. it’s on page 180 in `scrguide.pdf` ;-)